# What is the correct/right code for uploading or inserting values from input html tag into mysql using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, database-connection

What is the correct/right code for uploading or inserting values from input html tag into mysql using php?

I have php file and html file, but when I try to click the submit button, it only display the php file. My phpMyAdmin connected to my web host, while the html page is not

Html code:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="contract_num"><br>
    <input type="text" name="random_file"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?
 $contract_num=$_POST['contract_num'];
 $random_file=$_POST['random_file'];
mysql_connect("your.hostaddress.com", "username", "password")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("contract")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `contract` VALUES ('$contract_num', '$random_file')");
Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; 
?>
```

Comment: What do you actually mean?

Comment: i would settle for figuratively

Comment: is this solved?? if not let me know

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 solved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean "What is the correct/right code for this one?"

Please call first the html page or including the php file.

Created a page **add.php**, which contains this.

```
<?
 $contract_num=$_POST['contract_num'];
 $random_file=$_POST['random_file'];
mysql_connect("your.hostaddress.com", "username", "password")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("contract")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `contract` VALUES ('$contract_num', '$random_file')");
Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; 
?>
```

Then a page **form.php**, which includes the **add.php**

```
<?php
include "add.php";
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="contract_num"><br>
    <input type="text" name="random_file"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
</form>
```

You can call first the **form.php** in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form the post request is send to your **php** file. That is when you submit your form all the data filled inside the form will send to post your php file and it is processed there. If you want to see the html file again try to redirect to html file like

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send them via javascript, call a js function on 'submit' click , read all input and redirect to 'add.php' page with parameters ..